# Convert form to image with high quality

Tags: c#, forms, image, bitmap

A need to convert my form to image and after that image to pdf. I did that, used iTextsharp for converting image in pdf and used this code for converting my form to image:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(BackgroundPanel.Width, BackgroundPanel.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        BackgroundPanel.DrawToBitmap(bmp, BackgroundPanel.ClientRectangle);

        bmp.Save("image.png");
```

This code works, but I am not satisfied with quality of image, it's blurry and I want higher quality.

Is there any other way to make image of my form?

Comment: You can't make a picture better than the camera that took the picture or the format that is was stored at.  The only way of improving is use a tool like Photoshop which can perform dsp algorithms to enhance picture.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with jdwengs comment. With that being said, I have not testet this but you could try and give different arguments to the Save-function. As I can see in the documentation of the Bitmap Class the Save-function allows you to specify what format the picture should be saved in aswell as giving different encoders. I do not myself know if any of these works, but you can try and play around with the possible parameters and see if it will result in something positive.

I think it is worth trying since I have tried something similar in Python, where playing around with the arguments actually gave a better quality.

The Bitmap class documentation can be found just by simply searching for it on Google. Good luck.

Comment: I will watch and try that, thanks anyway. 
I am watching to different way to do this and that is with reports. I was reading literature about that and I think it's more practical and more useful.